# Data location specification and bytes32

Tags: solidity, memory, calldata

Why is data location not required to be specified for bytes32?

Comment: Hello. Please give us more details about your question. What do you mean by "data location not required" ? What exactly are you talking about ? What type would require it ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain In solidity, there are 4 types of data location: storage, calldata, stack and memory. Data location must be explicitly specified in solidity for arrays, bytes and structs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not you need to declare `memory`, `storage`, or `calldata` depends on if your variable is a "complex" variable or not. (See the note [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/types.html#data-location).) This means things like structs and arrays. Simpler types are automatically assigned `storage` - see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9781/68501) question and anwser.

To answer fully, `bytes32` will automatically be `storage` even without a data location declaration.

Comment: Thanks, that fully answered it!

Comment: `bytes` is a monster that probably should have gotten a different name to distinguish it further from the simple types like `bytes32`.